# How to change window opacity using mouse wheel or shortcut in Xfce 4.12?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, system-settings, transparency

I tried some advice [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228495), but it doesn't work. I want window opacity be changed on mouse wheel or on shortcut pressed (like in KDE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got solution from [here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=48250#p48250).
First execute this to disable zoom: `xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/zoom_desktop -T`
Then adjust opacity using Alt+mouse wheel on window's titlebar.